# ADF - use activity error code to determine pipeline outcome

Tags: azure-data-factory

I've got a pipeline that gets delimited files and imports to Azure SQL database.

Sometimes the files have trailing delimiters, which copy data interprets as columns with no header and throws a "DelimitedTextColumnNameNotAllowNull" error.

To deal with this, I use a dataflow instead of a copy data activity and get rid of the dodgy columns with a select transformation.

What I want to do is to use a copy data activity, and only process via the dataflow if there are trailing delimiters. I want to do this by trying the copydata, reading the error into a variable and running the dataflow if the error = "DelimitedTextColumnNameNotAllowNull" like this:

[image]

I think that will work, but I don't know how to isolate the error code from the error message.
I'm setting my Error variable like this:

[image]

But that gives me the entire json error message, and I only want the part highlighted so I can use it in my If condition:

[image]

I was thinking I could maybe use @json function, but I don't know if that's the right way of getting it, as I can't get the syntax correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below dynamic expression to get the exact error.

```
@split(split(activity('Copy data1').output.errors[0].Message,',')[0],'=')[1]
```

[image]

Ignore the warning here.

**Result:**

[image]

You should not use Data flow activity outside the if activity. You need to keep it inside either True or False activities of if activity based on the if activity expression.

Also, **if you want to achieve the expression without any activity error**, you can try the below workaround as well.

For this you need to use two datasets. **One for the lookup activity and another for the Copy and dataflows.**

Give the below configurations for the lookup dataset.

[image]

And for second dataset keep the below configurations.

[image]

First take a lookup activity and select **First row only** in it and it will give the output like below on debug.

[image]

Here, if the file's first row ends with `\t`, then we need to use Dataflow for that file and if not, we need to use Copy activity for that file.

To check whether it ends with `\t` or not use if activity. Give the below expression in the if activity.

```
@endswith(encodeUriComponent(activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.Prop_0),'%09')
```

[image]

Here for sample, I am checking it using set variables. You need to give the Dataflow activity inside True activities and copy activity inside the False activity.

If it not ends with `\t` the file will be copied through copy activity.

Comment: Amazing - thanks. Exactly what I was after.
Thanks for the other examples - really useful as well - but I think i'll stick with the 'try copy if fail do dataflow' because I'm trying to dynamically handle any kind of delimiter in the source file. I've got the expected file metadata stored in a database so for a given datasource 'type' I know what the delimiter is and I read that into the pipeline.
So I think that it should fail for any trailing delimiter and handle it accordingly?

Comment: Yes It will work.